# EclipseLink don't load properties from DataSource in Websphere Liberty Profile

Tags: jpa, jdbc, eclipselink, datasource, websphere-liberty

I have problem with configuring JPA in Websphere Liberty Profile. EclipseLink which is default provider in WAS with feature jpa-2.1 don't read the properties from created in server.xml DataSource. I've tried to get connection from this data source without JPA and this connection was succesfull, i had access to database. But when i use JPA and then create EntityManagerFactory from my PerstistenceUnit i get exception which in my opinion means that i didn't give required parameters such as url, username and password. I tested that WAS recognize EclipseLink provider, but now i don't know what can I do with this problem. Google haven't helped me.

Persistence.xml

```
<persistence version="1.0"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="test-unit" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <jta-data-source>java:comp/env/jdbc/PostgreDS</jta-data-source>
    <properties>
        <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="drop-and-create-tables" />
        <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode"
            value="database" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

server.xml(only part with my setting of JDBC and DS)

```
<jdbcDriver id="myJDBCDriver" libraryRef="JDBCLib" javax.sql.XADataSource="org.postgresql.xa.PGXADataSource" >
</jdbcDriver>
<library id="JDBCLib" name="PostgreLib">
    <file name="/home/hubert/JavaLibs/postgresql-9.4-1206-jdbc41.jar" id="JDBC_JAR"></file>
</library>

<dataSource id="PostrgreConnection" jdbcDriverRef="myJDBCDriver" jndiName="jdbc/PostgreDS" type="javax.sql.XADataSource">
    <properties URL="jdbc:postgresql://localhost/GotSpotDB" databaseName="GotSpotDB" password="testtest" portNumber="5432" serverName="localhost" user="GotSpotAdmin"/>

</dataSource>
```

Logs

```
[ERROR   ] CWWJP9992E: Exception [EclipseLink-4021] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.1.WAS-v20160106-a06c2b3): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Exception Description: Unable to acquire a connection from driver [null], user [null] and URL [null].  Verify that you have set the expected driver class and URL.  Check your login, persistence.xml or sessions.xml resource.  The jdbc.driver property should be set to a class that is compatible with your database platform
[ERROR   ] SRVE0777E: Exception thrown by application class 'org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy:837'
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-4021] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.1.WAS-v20160106-a06c2b3): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Exception Description: Unable to acquire a connection from driver [null], user [null] and URL [null].  Verify that you have set the expected driver class and URL.  Check your login, persistence.xml or sessions.xml resource.  The jdbc.driver property should be set to a class that is compatible with your database platform
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:837)
    at [internal classes]
    at pl.almost.done.TestServlet.doGet(TestServlet.java:52)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at [internal classes]
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-4021] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.1.WAS-v20160106-a06c2b3): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Exception Description: Unable to acquire a connection from driver [null], user [null] and URL [null].  Verify that you have set the expected driver class and URL.  Check your login, persistence.xml or sessions.xml resource.  The jdbc.driver property should be set to a class that is compatible with your database platform
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.unableToAcquireConnectionFromDriverException(DatabaseException.java:383)
    ... 4 more
```

Comment: Using `java:comp/env/jdbc/PostgreDS` in your persistence.xml won't work unless you have a `<resource-ref>` configured to make the binding from `jdbc/PostgreDS` -> `java:comp/env/jdbc/PostgreDS`.  Can you update your question with any sort of bindings you have configured?

Comment: I solved the problem. Using JPA needs to set property "driver" in persistence.xml additionally. Now all works.

Comment: You only have to set the driver property it you are using JPA in JSE mode. If you are using the JEE level JPA provided by Liberty you shouldn't have to set that property.